# PHP文字列の分割

Tags: php

PHPで、 
ある変数$hoge 
があるとします

$hogeを、 
１、２に分割したいと思います

１は、$hogeの先頭から32文字、 
２は、１の残りで、最大38文字

に分割するにはどのような書き方をすればよいでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: multipost https://teratail.com/questions/62425

Answer (score 1):

別解として `preg_match()` を使う場合などを。

```
preg_match('/^(.{32})(.{0,38})/',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    $match);

echo "$match[1]\n";
echo "$match[2]\n";
=>
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345
6789
```

Answer (score 0):

単純なのだとこうかな

```
//先頭(0文字目)から32文字目まで
$a1=substr($hoge, 0, 32);
//33文字目から最後まで
$a2=substr($hoge, 33);
```

一旦配列にするならこうかな

```
//32文字区切りで配列にする
$arr=str_split($hoge, 32);
//先頭要素切り取り
$a1=array_shift($arr);
//残り結合
$a2=implode($arr);
```